# How to open a native app in Flutter using assetlinks?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview, android-webview

I currently have a simple Flutter app running on Android. The Flutter app consist mostly of a webview, and when the user navigates in the webview, it should redirect to an Applink registered by a different application, eg: `https://www.bank.com`, for which a Bank application has been installed, and which registered an Applink at `https://www.bank.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json`.

When the user uses the Webview to navigate, instead of opening the native application, the HTML view is displayed in the webview. I've tried working around this by using `url_launcher`, like this:

```
      onNavigationRequest: (navigation) {         
        if(navigation.url.startsWith('https://www.bank.com')) {
          _launchURL(navigation.url);
          return NavigationDecision.prevent;
        }

        return NavigationDecision.navigate;
      },
```

But this doesn't work, since it fails with:

```
I/UrlLauncher(17085): component name for https://www.bank.com is null
```

Any suggestions how I can trigger the native app from the Flutter webview?

Answer (score 0):

I found out of to do it. To do so, you'd have to use the `url_launcher` plugin, and you'd have to configure it correctly by adding the `https` scheme to the list of queries which, confusingly, is not documented:

```
<queries>
    <!-- If your app checks for https support -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Then, using the following function, you can launch the URL:

```
_launchURL(String input) async {
var url = Uri.parse(input);

if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
  await launchUrl(url);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}}
```